# Simple_html_dom qual a diferença entre as duas URL's?

Tags: php, html, dom, web-scraping

Url2 funciona e consegue extrair os dados, Url1 não.

```
<?php 

include "simple_html_dom.php";
$CARDGALGO = file_get_html("$URLX");

echo $CARDGALGO;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depurei o script e notei que a URL1 passa o limite do `MAX_FILE_SIZE`, que atualmente é de 600000, veja no `simple_html_dom.php` linha 66:

```
 define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000);
```

Então você pode aumentar este limite ou pode deixar de usar libs extras **e usar a API nativa do PHP**:

- http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php

Exemplo:

```
<?php

$URL1 = "http://ladbrokes.365dm.com/greyhounds/profile/dog/oor-millie/3334094";

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile($URL1);
```

Para pegar um elemento especifico você pode usar:

- Pegar por ID http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php
- Pegar todos elementos de um tipo http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Pegar o texto de um elemento especifico pelo ID:

```
<?php

$URL1 = "http://ladbrokes.365dm.com/greyhounds/profile/dog/oor-millie/3334094";

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile($URL1);

echo 'Texto:', $doc->getElementById('logo')->textContent, '<br>';
```

> Este exemplo pega esta parte da página atual:
>
> ```
> <header id="header" role="banner">
>     <div class="hix">
>         <a href="greyhounds" id="logo">Ladbrokes</a>
>                 <div id="nav-mobile-open"></div>
>             </div>            
> </header>
> ```

Para pegar todos elementos de um tipo, como todos links, seria algo como:

```
<?php

$URL1 = "http://ladbrokes.365dm.com/greyhounds/profile/dog/oor-millie/3334094";

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile($URL1);

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    echo 'Texto:', $node->textContent, '<br>';
}
```

---

### Usando [DOMXpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

Mas com certeza a maneira mais pratica de pegar elementros especificos é usar o XPath, como nessa página a coluna "4" de cada linha na tabela representa o nome do treinador então o XPath a ser usado seria algo como:

```
//tr/td[4]
```

Exemplo:

```
<?php

$URL1 = "http://ladbrokes.365dm.com/greyhounds/profile/dog/oor-millie/3334094";

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile($URL1);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$colunas = $xpath->query("//tr/td[4]");

echo 'Treinadores:<br>';

foreach ($colunas as $node) {
    $nome = trim($node->textContent);
    echo ' - ', $nome, '<br>';
}
```

---

### Evitando os avisos/warnings por causa de erros de HTML em uma página

Esses links que você adicioneou possuem muitos erros de HTML, o que pode emitir muitos warnings, então para evitar isto ser exibido você pode simplesmente ligar e delisgar os erros internos da API, assim:

```
<?php

$URL1 = "http://ladbrokes.365dm.com/greyhounds/profile/dog/oor-millie/3334094";

$doc = new DOMDocument;

$estadoOriginal = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc->loadHTMLFile($URL1);

libxml_clear_errors();

libxml_use_internal_errors($estadoOriginal);
```

Comment: Impressionante. Muito obrigado. Num primeiro momento como o código já está todo escrito utilizando o Simple vou apenas mudar o MAX_FILE_SIZE porém na proxima atualização reescreverei utilizando o DOMXPath. Obrigado pela rapidez em solucionar meu problema.